# Shapefile is saved in EPSG:4326 despite being set to EPSG:32651 via geopandas

Tags: python, coordinate-system, geopandas, wgs84, utm

This is the code

```
def loadPoint():
    df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\imper\Documents\new_GISfiles\earthquakesPH\emscPhilippines2008to2020_lonLat.csv')
    geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df.Longitude, df.Latitude)]
    crs = 'GEOGCS["WGS 84",' \
          'DATUM["WGS_1984",' \
          'SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,' \
          'AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]], ' \
          'PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],' \
          'UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,' \
          'AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],' \
          'AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]' \
          'PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"], ' \
          'PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],' \
          'PARAMETER["central_meridian",123],' \
          'PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],' \
          'PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],' \
          'PARAMETER["false_northing",0],' \
          'UNIT["metre",1,' \
          'AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],' \
          'AXIS["Easting",EAST],' \
          'AXIS["Northing",NORTH],' \
          'AUTHORITY["EPSG","32651"]]'
    geo_df = GeoDataFrame(df, crs=crs, geometry=geometry)
    geo_df.to_file(driver='ESRI Shapefile', filename='eqpts.shp')

def plotPoint():
    basemap = gpd.read_file(r'C:\Users\imper\Documents\new_GISfiles\earthquakesPH\PH_provs.shp')   
    pt = gpd.read_file(r'C:\Users\imper\Documents\new_GISfiles\earthquakesPH\eqpts.shp')
    ax = basemap.plot(cmap = 'jet', column = 'NAME_1', figsize=(10,10)) 
    pt.plot(ax=ax, marker="o", color="red", markersize=5)

loadPoint()
plotPoint()
```

But CRS is wrong

```
pt.crs
Out[44]: {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
```

CSV is from [EMSC](https://www.emsc-csem.org/Earthquake/?filter=yes&start_date=2004-10-01&end_date=2020-05-01&region=BABUYAN%20ISL%20REGION%2C%20PHILIPPINES%7CBATAN%20ISL%20REGION%2C%20PHILIPPINES%7CBOHOL%2C%20PHILIPPINES%7CCATANDUANES%2C%20PHILIPPINES%7CLEYTE%2C%20PHILIPPINES%7CLUZON%2C%20PHILIPPINES%7CMASBATE%20REGION%2C%20PHILIPPINES%7CMINDANAO%2C%20PHILIPPINES%7CMINDORO%2C%20PHILIPPINES%7CMORO%20GULF%2C%20MINDANAO%2C%20PHILIPPINES%7CNEGROS%2C%20PHILIPPINES%7CNEGROS-%20CEBU%20REG%2C%20PHILIPPINES%7CPALAWAN%2C%20PHILIPPINES%7CPANAY%2C%20PHILIPPINES%7CSAMAR%2C%20PHILIPPINES%7CSIBUYAN%20SEA%2C%20PHILIPPINES%7CSULU%20ARCHIPELAGO%2C%20PHILIPPINES%7CVISAYAN%20SEA%2C%20PHILIPPINES&felt=on&min_intens=0&max_intens=8&view=25) (earthquaks location)

> Latitude,Longitude
>
> 13.81,121.1
>
> 13.76,120.92
>
> 10.45,125.2
>
> 6.69,125.23

Comment: Shouldnt `crs = {'init' :'epsg:32651'}` be enough?

Comment: I tried that but when i type pt.crs in the module, it comes as no projection as in {}.

Comment: Added the csv! @BERA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the last version of Geopandas:

> Starting with GeoPandas 0.7, the .crs attribute of a GeoSeries or GeoDataFrame stores the CRS information as a pyproj.CRS, and no longer as a proj4 string or dict.

Therefore your crs is not correct

Use

```
crs = "EPSG:32651"
```

or

```
crs = "+proj=utm +zone=51 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"
```

or

```
crs = 'PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 51N",GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.01745329251994328,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",123],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],AUTHORITY["EPSG","32651"],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH]]'
```

Result:

```
geo_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, crs=crs, geometry=geometry)
geo_df.crs
<Projected CRS: EPSG:32651>
Name: WGS 84 / UTM zone 51N
Axis Info [cartesian]:
- [east]: Easting (metre)
- [north]: Northing (metre)
Area of Use:
- undefined
Coordinate Operation:
- name: UTM zone 51N
- method: Transverse Mercator
Datum: World Geodetic System 1984
- Ellipsoid: WGS 84
- Prime Meridian: Greenwich
```

With and old version, as BERA says

```
crs = {'init' :'epsg:32651'}
geo_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, crs=crs, geometry=geometry)
geo_df.crs
{'init': 'epsg:32651'}
```

Comment: I'll try this later if it works. Thank you!

Comment: The first one worked! But when it is saved as shp and imported via geopandas, the crs is lost. Thank you anyways.